# Updating a dictionary with index of an input string as we iterate over the string- O(n) or O(1) space complexity?

Tags: python, space-complexity

My question is around the Space Complexity of updating a `dictionary` with an `input string`.

e.g. `string = "thisisarandomstring"`, `my_dict = dict()`

Say we iterate over the input string, and for each character, we store and update the index of the latest character.

i.e.

```
for i in range(len(string)): 
    my_dict[string[i]] = i
```

Would the `space complexity` for the above be `O(n)? Or O(1)`?

In the question I am solving the solution says it is O(n), but the way I see it, we will store at most 26 characters in the dictionary, so should't it be O(1)? I can see that the number of updates would be dependent on the length of the input string, but does this impact the space? Since for every update, we replace what was the previous index of the seen before element.

Comment: Your dict will have no more keys than there are unicode code points, from which you could work out an upper CONSTANT bound for its memory consumption. So I'm saying O(1).

Comment: Depends on the size of the alphabet (could be much more then 26) I would say. Then still if all the test strings are relatively short one would not reach the `O(1)` range, but would stay in the `O(N)` part, which for real languages is more of a `O(root(N))` as the unique letters in a text do not grow linear with the total letters.

Comment: @schwobaseggl If you can give a number of bytes that will always be greater than OP's dictionary no matter the string, it's O(1). And I think you could, as there are not infinite unicode code points (in use). edit: if we're not counting the space for the input string itself, as Muhteva pointed out.

Comment: I am not arguing aaginst the general point mase the OP, just giving an explanation for why a system trying to autodetect the space usage would detect something different. But even with a (nearly) infintie alphabet the bound should be less than `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, eventually we can store 26 different keys in `dictionary`, therefore space consumed by the `dictionary` will be constant, that is `O(1)`. However you are creating a `string` variable that consists of `n` characters. The space complexity of storing a new string of length `n` is `Θ(n)` because each individual character must be stored somewhere. Therefore that may be the reason why it is indicated as `O(n)`.

Btw, if we denote the space complexity (amount of space consumed) as `f(n)`. Then `f(n)` ∈ `O(1)` indicates `f(n)` ∈ `O(n)`. Therefore `f(n)` ∈ `O(n)` is not a wrong statement. Well, technically.

Comment: True, but usually such problems are concerned with *extra* space where the string  constitutes the problem itself and is not part of the solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was a little bit hesitated to say that this is the reason why they indicated the space complexity of the solution as ```O(n)```. If it's not the case, then it's wrong. Space complexity should be ```O(1)```. Because there is no difference between giving a string of 26 characters and a string of 26 million characters in terms of space.

Comment: You could write a string class that interns all available characters, making it O(1) in any case. :D

Comment: Rather than taking the input as ```string```, we can traverse through the characters and update the ```dictionary``` accordingly. So, we can avoid creating a string of length n, which makes it ```O(1)``` in any case as you stated.